# iOS auto layouts - Equal Height constraint in an xib

Tags: autolayout

I am having a xib where I have added a UIView as subview to the main view. I want this subview to be of a proportionate height to the main view. But there is no 'Equals Height' option to do it. I would have been able to do this had it been a view controller in a storyboard.

[image]

So how to achieve a constraint where the subview's height is a ratio of superview's height (say 3:4).

Comment: Set up top space and bottom space constraints and adjust their values until the ratio looks good.

Comment: I could do that. But screen sizes will change with different iPhone. Setting a ratio would have been the perfect way.

Comment: Screen sizes wil change with different iPhone models. Correct. But even the `UIView` will change accordingly if you set the right constraints. And it will look different on every device.

Comment: Check out this demo I made to show you: https://www.dropbox.com/s/aecn78q6bsyb06g/Demo.zip?dl=0.

Comment: Cannot open Dropbox right now, will check later anyway. Thanks for putting it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it can only be done programmatically in this case.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
   self.scannedDetailsCardHeightConstraint.constant = self.view.frame.size.height*(0.4);    
   [self.view layoutSubviews];}
```

Comment: Just marking it as an answer as it seems a lot better to do it programatically.

Answer (score 1):

It seems odd that you can't do this.  Here is a workaround.

1. Add a view to the top level view.
2. Pin its top, left, right, and bottom to the top level view's top, left, right, and bottom.  Make all offsets 0.
3. Now you can add a view to this and use Equal Height and Equal Width constraints as you would expect.

[image]

Comment: So I need to add another top level view just for that? Another view apart, that's going to be a lot of additional constraints in the 'document outline'. Doing it programmatically seems to be lot simpler then.

Comment: Just 4 extra constraints. Not bad really, but it's nice to have a choice.

Comment: After setting it up, you just ignore the top level view and lay everything out in the second view.

Comment: Thanks :) But its actually clutter. Imagine a situation where this view has actually many other subviews.

Comment: Xcode should just have allowed to do it the easy way.

Comment: Those four constraints are on the top level view and they will be the only 4 constraints ever at that level. You don't even need to open the triangle to look at them.

Comment: I'm not saying it is optimal, but it's not the end of the world either. That is the essence of a work around. If you want to do it in Interface Builder, this gives you a method to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can modify the xib file to fulfill this.

Create a space constraint between subview.left and superview.left. Save the xib and open it in Sublime (or other editor).The code will be like

```
<constraint firstItem="Tnc-ek-Ibw" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="iN0-l3-epB" secondAttribute="leading" id="1Go-h7-fVl"/>
```

The `Tnc-ek-Ibw` is identifier of your subview and the `iN0-l3-epB` is superview's.(`1Go-h7-fVl` is identifier of this constraint, ignore it.)

Looks familiar? Yes, if you set "Equals Height" in storyboard as you would have been able to, the code in storyboard will be very similar. The only difference is **`attribute`**. Now modify both `attribute` from `leading` to `width`. The code now will be like this

```
<constraint firstItem="Tnc-ek-Ibw" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="iN0-l3-epB" secondAttribute="width" id="1Go-h7-fVl"/>
```

Save it and reopen it in Xcode. It works!

I don't know why can not do this in Xcode, maybe it is a bug, I'm not sure.

This skill is undocumented. Anyway, it works.